# Repeat the same code in several classes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, logging

I have this two functions in my project, that will be identical across several classes.

I cannot create a common base class, since they inherit from different classes (some are UIViewControllers, some are NSObjects, etc.).

I tried with categories, but again, as I don't have a base class, there isn't a single place where to put them. Neither I want the functions to be available in all UIViewControllers, so creating a category there wouldn't help.

**How can I add this code to the classes I want without copy & paste?**

---

Just for the record, I'm implementing [dynamic log levels in cocoalumberjack](http://code.google.com/p/cocoalumberjack/wiki/DynamicLogLevels), and the code I need to add is the following:

```
static int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_WARN;

+ (int)ddLogLevel
{
        return ddLogLevel;
}

+ (void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel
{
        ddLogLevel = logLevel;
}
```

Comment: Neither is this my own finding, nor does it justify an answer, so I make it a comment. Mike Ash had [a great post](http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-19-creating-classes-at-runtime-for-fun-and-profit.html) in his excellent _Friday Q&A_ series, that might help here: The idea would be to add the methods at runtime. Note: Since these are class-methods they need to be added to the meta-class. (Oh and: yes, it's a bit hackish...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit messy perhaps, but you could use a #define.  Create a header file with the following in it:

```
//LoggingCode.h

#define LOGGING_CODE static int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_WARN; \
\
+ (int)ddLogLevel \
{ \
    return ddLogLevel; \
} \
\
+ (void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel \
{ \
    ddLogLevel = logLevel; \
}
```

Make sure the header file is included whenever you want to use this code, and just insert LOGGING_CODE where you want it.

```
#include "LoggingCode.h"

LOGGING_CODE
```

The C preprocessor will do the rest.

Comment: Messy indeed, but this was what I finally did. I wish there was an easier way to add code to a class, something like Ruby mixins...

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't inherit from a common class, you could make a static class that you would call from both of your other classes.

---

Edit:

StaticClass.h

```
+(int)commonddLogLevel;
+(void)commonddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel;
```

Class1.h

```
+(int)ddLogLevel;
+(void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel;
```

Class1.m

```
+(int)ddLogLevel {
    [StaticClass commonddLogLevel];
}

+(void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel {
    [StaticClass commonddSetLogLevel:logLevel];
}
```

Class2.h

```
+(int)ddLogLevel;
+(void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel;
```

Class2.m

```
+(int)ddLogLevel {
    [StaticClass commonddLogLevel];
}

+(void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel {
    [StaticClass commonddSetLogLevel:logLevel];
}
```

Comment: That won't work, because cocoalumberjack searches for the classes that have those two methods... I need those methods to be defined in the class, but I don't want to have the repeated code.

Comment: Maybe, if the code was more complicated, something like that could be useful. But the original code is already one line per method, so I don't see it as an improvement.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I hope you find a solution to this very particular problem.

Comment: thanks for your time. I'm not sure there is a solution to this I'll feel comfortable with...